# Limit to number of simple products I am able to add to a Bundle

Tags: magento-1.6, bundled-product, bundle, bundle-product

I am running version 1.6.2.0 and something has happened where by I am unable to add more than 94 simple products in total to a bundle product I have created.

I have 3 options and want to have 45 simple products per option, but as I am adding once I get up to this number of having 94 in total across all three Magento says it has saved but when I scroll down and check it has not saved the last product I tried adding to the option. I dont get any error message, everything appears to be fine, but it just doesnt add anymore products once I get to 94!

I can remove products from other options to allow me to add to others, but cannot exceed this 94 limit! It's like a 1 in one out rule!

It never used to be like this - I used to be able to have 50+ products per option. Only recent thing I can think of that might affect this is we bought a couple of 3rd party asynchronous chaching and indexing plug-ins. However, we've even treid disabling these and trying to save but the same problem remains!

Anyone any idea?

Comment: Any change to server configuration?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because there has been no response from the OP or others in several months.

Comment: To me it sounds like the reason could be the suhosin configuration for the maximum number of input variables. Can you check this setting?